# Changes in quants in Odoo 11 , 12

Tags: odoo, odoo-11, odoo-12

Up to Odoo 10, I used Quants fields `inventory_value`, `cost` in some of my reports to calculate purchase cost, etc.... and also I used quants relation to moves in some cases. 
Now as I started working with Odoo 12 I see that there are no relations from `stock.quant` to `stock.move` and `stock_quant_move_rel` table is gone.

As I can see, now I can not even check inventory value in Odoo 12?

So maybe can someone explain these changes that were made, and how is workflow is changed, because I'm a little bit lost now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In inventory there is inventory valuation menu under reporting you can check inventory value product wise or In product template you can check quantity on hand to check stock quant.